# NullPointerException while using TinyDB

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android (and not a veteran at all in java) developpment.

Trying to do a weather app, I'm trying to use TinyDB as my storage for saved cities.
A button on another activity let me add cities to a list (which I want to save).

In my MainActivity's onCreate, I'm setting up my TinyDB. Then add a city stored in extra to my TinyDB if the MainActivity is launched from the addCityActivity. Finally, getting all the cities from TinyDB to print it to screen in a ListView. (user will then be able to click on a city to get weather information for this one)

But then a NullPointerException raises and it seems to come from TinyDB and I have no idea how to resolve it, I'm stuck on it for a day now (doing this on my free time).

Do you guys have any idea please ?

TinyDB is [here](https://github.com/kcochibili/TinyDB--Android-Shared-Preferences-Turbo#readme).

And here's my MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Context context;
    private ListView cityListView;
    private CitylistAdapter citylistAdapter;

    private List<City> cities = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TinyDB tinydb = new TinyDB(context);

        if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
            String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("City");
            ArrayList<String> cityList = tinydb.getListString("Cities");
            cityList.add(getIntent().getStringExtra("City"));
            tinydb.putListString("Cities", cityList);
        }

        ArrayList<String> cityList = tinydb.getListString("Cities");
        for (int i = 0; i < cityList.size(); i++) {
            City city = new City();
            city.setName(cityList.get(i));
            cities.add(city);
        }

        this.cityListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.cityList);

        this.citylistAdapter = new CitylistAdapter(getApplicationContext(), cities);
        this.cityListView.setAdapter(citylistAdapter);

        FloatingActionButton addCity = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.openAddCity);

        addCity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startAddCityActivity();
            }
        });
    }

    private void startAddCityActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddCityActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

And here's the stack trace :

```
2021-09-23 13:59:38.565 5754-5754/com.example.weather E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.weather, PID: 5754
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.weather/com.example.weather.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
        at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferencesName(PreferenceManager.java:555)
        at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(PreferenceManager.java:545)
        at com.example.weather.TinyDB.<init>(TinyDB.java:39)
        at com.example.weather.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:51)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
2021-09-23 13:59:38.600 5754-5754/com.example.weather I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 5754 SIG: 9
```

Comment: The complete exception stack trace is very useful in determining cause - you can find it in the logcat window if using Studio.  Post it in your question.  - Although I see your issue straight away - you never initialize `context` and provide it to `TinyDB` in its constructor.  An activity is a context so in theory you could just use `this` in the actual parameter.

Comment: Added it now, thanks!

Comment: you've defined `private Context context;` and didn't assign it a value when you use it at `TinyDB tinydb = new TinyDB(context);`. also, using a variable like `private Context context;` is probably a bad idea already

Comment: And it works, thank you. Context is a bit weird for me now but that's a bit clearer!